# "none of the language" -- "none of" with an abstract noun

Tags: determiners

" I spoke little to none of the language"

Can we use *none of* with an abstract noun?

Found it here:  https://greenhearttravel.org/blog/high-school-abroad/6-reasons-why-traveling-abroad-is-important-for-young-people

It seems like we can say about a vegetable that "none of it is edible". Does it also apply to abstract nouns?

Comment: "Little, if any" might be more idiomatic (meaning _so little that it might as well be none_).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example:

- "None of the love they used to share remained."
- "He had none of his sister's imagination."